# Commands not executed in macos terminal, why?

Tags: macos, laravel, terminal, composer-php, zsh

I have a question..

1. I install ZSH, Composer, Laravel Installer;
2. In ~/.zshrc in `$PATH` i added "~/.composer/vendor/bin".
3. When I execute `echo $PATH`, I get string:

> ~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:

But when I try to execute

```
laravel new blog
```

I get an error message

> zsh: command not found: laravel.

If i create an alias - it's worked fine.

Composer also not working without an alias.

So where is my problem? I think i change $PATH to not create alias, but it doesn't working.

```
    # Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
    export ZSH=/Users/davydov/.oh-my-zsh

    # Set name of the theme to load.
    # Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
    # Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
    # time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
    ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

    # Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
    # CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
    # DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
    # export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

    # Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
    # DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
    # DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
    # ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

    # Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
    # COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

    # Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
    # under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
    # much, much faster.
    # DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

    # Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
    # stamp shown in the history command output.
    # The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
    # HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

    # Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
    # ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

    # Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
    # Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
    # Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
    # Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
    plugins=(git)

    # User configuration

    export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:"
    # export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

    source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

    # You may need to manually set your language environment
    # export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

    # Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
    # if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
    #   export EDITOR='vim'
    # else
    #   export EDITOR='mvim'
    # fi

    # Compilation flags
    # export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

    # ssh
    # export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/dsa_id"

    # Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
    # plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
    # users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
    # For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
    #
    # Example aliases
    # alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
    # alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

    source  ~/.aliases
```

[image: Location of .composer and .zshrc]

Comment: could you edit your question with your zsh config?

Comment: It shouldn't show `~` with you echo `$PATH`. Replace `~` with `$HOME` in your zshrc or make sure `~/` in it is not inside quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `~/.zshrc` in $PATH i added `"~/.composer/vendor/bin"`

`"~/"` will not expand when sourced from `~/.zshrc` you need to use the full path to the directory (*i.e.*`/Users/groovyme/.composer/vendor/bin`) or an environment variable such as `$HOME` that will expand to that full path.

HTH

Comment: Yes, an inconvenient surprise if you are not used to shell programming.